# how to track internal hyper links of a website using php?

Tags: php

how to track internal hyper links of a website?
Actually i want to find out the total no.of internal and external links of a website.
but in the case of internal links there are alots of complications.what i mean is that some of its href attribute contains javascript,# etc.

Anyone knows the exact solution to track internal links.
that is links to the pages of the same website by using php?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for Google Analytics. They provide you with overlays over your website where you can see the links and the number of clicks.

Another tool I use regularly is [Xenu Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) to show broken (and non-broken) links.

Comment: Google Analytics (or did you mean Google Webmaster Tools?) works only if the domain belongs to you :)

Comment: Well, then try something with php.